# Неконстантный константный метод

Tags: c++

Есть константный метод, но он изменяет одно из полей. За то, что это поле можно изменять и в константном объекте я отвечаю, но компилятор мне не верит на слово, что можно сделать?

```
class A
{
public:
    void funct() const;
private:
    int a;
    int b;
}
void A::funct() const
{
    b++;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить mutable к объявлению переменной:
mutable int b;
Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2005/10/mutable-constcast.html)

Comment: - А еще лучше — **не пробуйте:**

> Один добавленный `mutable` элементарно может привести к каскадным нагромождениям `mutable` и к потере выгоды от использования `const` вообще.

- Если вы точно знаете, что делаете, лучше используйте `const_cast<T>` в строго определенном месте и документируйте этот костыль — почему невозможно / невероятно сложно в конкретном месте написать `const-`корректный код.

Comment: - Насколько мне известно, в `C++` у `mutable` есть только одно применение — реализация `getter'а` с ленивой инициализацией. В этом случае стоит локализовать использование `mutable` в классе-хелпере типа `suspension<T>` из [**этого**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374743/c-const-getter-method-with-lazy-initialization) примера, и опять же, задокументировать почему был написан `mutable.`

Comment: Хм.. Интересное замечание..

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать: ну, всякий внутренний кэш должен быть mutable, по идее.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать хотелось бы посмотреть как будет выглядеть подсчет ссылок, например, без mutable =) Вы предлагаете костыль, если не хак, вместо специально введенной для таких целей конструкции.  
Ленивая инициализация по ссылке имеет кучу огрехов. Для такой цели есть boost::optional или будущий std::optional.